# simple append issue with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple question. My JS code is like this, but when I try to add a new element or content to the `<div>`, it comes up then goes up quickly. I don't know why.

How can I avoid this?

```
        <head>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#mybtn').click(function () {
                    $('#main').append('<button id ="mm" onclick="myfun()">generate code my fun.</button>');
                });
            });
         </head>
        <body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <button id ="mybtn">generate code</button>
            <div id="main"></div>
</form>
    </body>
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine: [http://jsfiddle.net/xCB4a/](http://jsfiddle.net/xCB4a/)

Comment: You could try setting the button `type`, example : `<button type="button" id="mybtn">generate code</button>`. This will stop the button from Submitting.

Comment: I ma including js code like this.  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> that cause to problem??

Comment: Is your content wrapped inside a `<form>` tag? (If its .ASPX then I guess it would be.) If so then try my suggestion of setting the `type` of the button.

Comment: Nunners pls write it answer I will approve it

Comment: so you did not include all of your code ...

Comment: correct answer COME FORM  from NUNNERS thank you

Comment: Next time please include all of your code - I do not see a form tag in your code

Comment: I am sorry G siry,u are right,I correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stop the button from Submitting the form by setting the button's `type` to be that of `button`.

Example :

```
<button type="button" id="mybtn">generate code</button>
```

The default type for a `<button>` element is submit. Which is causing your `<FORM>` tag to submit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#mybtn').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#main').append('<button id ="mm" onclick="myfun()">
generate code my fun </button>');
      return false;
});
```

Comment: but why this happen ,it is just a simple aspx page??there other some sample s on the net and works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$('#mybtn').click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#main').append('<button id ="mm" onclick="myfun()"> generate code my fun </button>');
});
```

`preventDefault` : *If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.*